# Mysql and Apache don't free memory after ending connections

Tags: mysql, centos, performance, httpd

My server goes down repeatedly. using `htop` I found that mysql and apache use almost all of RAM memory. When I restart apache everything is ok, but after a while httpd and mysql take all memory as you see in  the following sreenshot:

[image]

I'm sure that while the screenshot has been taken, there is maximum of 2-3 users online. and therefore httpd(or sometims mysqld) doesn't free memory after ending a connection.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check `netstat` for mysql connections marked as `TIME_WAIT`

Here are two suggestions:

## SUGGESTION #1

Try to make all mysql `TIME_WAIT` connections disconnect faster

Run these commands on all DB and Web Servers

```
SEC_TO_TIMEWAIT=0
echo ${SEC_TO_TIMEWAIT} > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
echo ${SEC_TO_TIMEWAIT} > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
```

## SUGGESTION #2

Keep track of all the mysql connections per web server

Create a script called /root/ShowMySQLConnections.sh with these lines

```
netstat | grep mysql > /root/mysql_netstat.txt
cat /root/mysql_netstat.txt | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/:/ /' |  awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | grep -v local > /root/mysql_netstat_iplist.txt
for IP in `cat /root/mysql_netstat_iplist.txt`
do
        ESCOUNT=`cat /root/mysql_netstat.txt | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '{print $5}' | grep -c "${IP}"`
        TWCOUNT=`cat /root/mysql_netstat.txt | grep TIME_WAIT   | awk '{print $5}' | grep -c "${IP}"`
        IPPAD=`echo "${IP}........................................" | cut -b -40`
        (( ESCOUNT += 1000000 ))
        (( TWCOUNT += 1000000 ))
        ES=`echo ${ESCOUNT} | cut -b 3-`
        TW=`echo ${TWCOUNT} | cut -b 3-`
        echo ${IPPAD} : ESTABLISHED:${ES} TIME_WAIT:${TW}
done
echo ; echo
netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed 's/d)/d/'
```

## EPILOGUE

After killing `TIME_WAIT` connections, run `watch /root/ShowMySQLConnections.sh` and see if the TIME_WAITs disappear.